# enverse-how to customize user id in customized revision listner

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-security, microservices, hibernate-envers

i am using jpa with hibernate envers of micro service.
i tried

```
public class MyRevisionEntityListener implements RevisionListener {
  @Override
  public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
    // If you use spring security, you could use SpringSecurityContextHolder.
    final UserContext userContext = UserContextHolder.getUserContext();
    MyRevisionEntity mre = MyRevisionEntity.class.cast( revisionEntity );       
    mre.setUserName( userContext.getUserName() );
  } 
}
```

it saves username better.but i want to save user name as"by system" when updates the record by another micro service and when user updates should save the user name as above.how to customize above code as my requirement

Answer (score 0):

It would seem the most logical based on your supplied code might be to simply add a boolean flag to your `UserContext` thread local variable and simply check that inside the listener.

By default this flag would be false but for your special microservice or business use case, you could alter that state temporarily, run your process, and clear that state after you've finished, very much like a web filter chain works in web applications.